# Matplotlib: Multiple plots with same layout (no automatic layout)

Tags: matplotlib, layout

I am trying to make several pie charts that I can then transition between in a presentation. For this, it would be very useful for the automatic layouting to... get out of the way. The problem is that whenever I change a label, the whole plot moves around on the canvas so that it fits perfectly. I'd like the plot to stay centered, so it occupies the same area every time. I have tried adding center=(0,0) to ax.pie(), but to no avail.

Two examples:
[Image smaller, left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfh3c.png)
[Image larger, right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJkim.png)

Instead of that effect, I'd like the pie chart to be in the middle of the canvas and have the same size in both cases (and I'd then manually make sure that the labels are on canvas by setting large margins).

The code I use to generate these two images is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Draw labels, from 
# https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py
def make_labels(ax, wedges, labs):
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
        bbox=bbox_props,
        zorder=0, va="center")
    for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
        if p.theta2-p.theta1 < 5:
            continue
        ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
        y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
        x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
        horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
        connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
        kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
        ax.annotate(labs[i], xy=(x, y),
            xytext=(1.1*x,1.1*y),
            horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

kw=dict(autoscale_on=False, in_layout=False, xmargin=1, ymargin=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=100, subplot_kw=kw)

wedges, texts = ax.pie(x=[1,2,3], radius=1,
                                  wedgeprops=dict(width=1),
                                  pctdistance=0.7,
                                  startangle=90,
                                  textprops=dict(fontsize=8),
                                  center=(0, 0))
make_labels(ax, wedges, ["long text", "b", "c"])
#make_labels(ax, wedges, ["a", "b", "long text"])
plt.show()
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you saving your figures? It looks like you may be using `savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')` which automatically resized the figure to include all the artists.

If I run your code with `fig.savefig(..., bbox_inches=None)`, I get the following output

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! However, the center still keeps moving around (albeit less) when I generate larger plots. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/Au7tPZbP) (exactly what I posted in the original question, just more data) that generates [these two images](https://imgur.com/a/xXzdh4v) - notice how the center moves.

Comment: Sorry, your code works for me. This is the result that I get https://imgur.com/aDai52q

Comment: That is creepy... But thanks, now I know that it should work. Could you tell me which versions of python and matplotlib you are using? Then maybe I could try to get it to work by matching your environment.

Comment: Python 3.7.4, matplotlib v3.2.1. I'm guessing it's more of a backend issue. I'm using ipympl v. 0.5.6 (Jupyter lab with %matplotlib widget).